# Telescopic downdraft installation

Tags: exhaust-vent, hood

I'm trying to install the telescopic downdraft for my island. ([installation guide](https://content.syndigo.com/asset/7fe32374-8de3-4278-a8e5-b5775984a6d8/original.pdf) - model KitchenAid KXD4630YSSSKU (30" downdraft))

Because it's an island I wanted the blower to be in the rear of the downdraft, so I unscrewed the blower box and installed it at the rear.

No red flag during the installation but after turning on the vent I notice that it was much (much) stronger before I did the change. The exhaust from the blower still blows super strongly, but the suction (from the telescopic part above the countertop, the "entrance" of the blower) is super weak.

What could have gone wrong?

- There is no "pipe" from the blower to the telescopic part above the countertop which leads me to think that if the whole system is air tight, then it should just work
- I ducted openings in the metal casing
- I don't see any conceptual difference before and after
- I didn't connect yet the vent to the crawlspace duct because I wanted to make sure everything was fine

Hopefully someone has experience and has encountered my case.

[image: read]

(note that when testing out I have the blower box screwed against the metal)

[image: front]

Comment: Did you follow the whole business with putting a '4-3/4" cover box (supplied)' on the front and make sure everything is sealed tight?

Comment: Could you have turned the fan 180 deg so it blows and sucks in the opposite direction?

Comment: Before and after, had you hooked up the vent pipe? And is that 4" instead of the manual specified 6"? And not to make you feel bad, but pg 8, "Do not use plastic or metal foil vent." At a minimum, I'd use a more rigid foil 6" flex pipe.

Comment: Foil is a terrible idea for kitchen vents (and not permitted as @AloysiusDefenestrate noted). The solid-flex aluminum is about minimum. This vent may be on fire at some point, and the duct needs to **contain that fire** until the grease burns itself out.

Comment: thanks for the comments. A specialist will come on Tuesday and help install it so I will see and update this thread. I don't know about the grease in fire as there are some filters before hand.